# Why is allow not allowed here in apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I've the following in my `httpd.conf` file:

```
<Directory "/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Options=Indexes,Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Next, I've a directory `ChatLogs` located in server root, with a `.htaccess` file defined as follows:

```
Allow from all
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /www/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
Require valid-user
```

and when I try to access the directory, I get a 500 server error with the following in server logs (`10.109.1.92` is my intranet IP):

```
[alert] [client 10.109.1.92] /www/ChatLogs/.htaccess: allow not allowed here
```

I understand that this is because of the following statement in `.htaccess` file:

```
Allow from all
```

but could someone explain **why is the `Allow` directive not allowed**? I want later to restrict access to certain IP address ranges; and would prefer if it can be placed in singular directories instead of setting them in `httpd.conf` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you've got a comma before Limit. That makes apache parse it as though it were part of Options rather than a separate override. Think of it like this:

```
AllowOverride 
               AuthConfig
               FileInfo 
               Options=Indexes,Limit
```

What you want is instead

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Limit Options=Indexes
```

There's more information at [the Apache core documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride).

Comment: But commas are allowed as per the documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Comment: Commas are allowed between **options**, to create a list of options.  `Limit` is a separate directive and should not be part of the list of options. I don't know how to put it any clearer than that.

Comment: <strike>Isn't the same true for `Indexes` as well?</strike> Never mind that. I understand now. :) I have had confused [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options) with AllowOverride Directive lists.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working! It can be a bit confusing with having a list within a list :-)